# Android Simulator Failing

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to install the Android environment for Eclipse, and am having an issue running a test program. The simulator starts, does the Android logo with the blinking underscore, but it only blinks 2 or 3 times, then becomes "Not Responding" (Windows Vista). The log in Eclipse merely says "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...". I've tried just launching the device from the SDK Manager, but it does the same thing. Here are the settings that i'm using for the virtual device, the same settings that work for my Mac perfectly.

```
Name: 2_2_Default_HVGA
Target: Android 2.2 - API Level 8
SD Card: -
Shapshot: Disabled
Skin: HVGA
Resolution: -
Hardware: Abstracted LCD Density: 160
Hardware: Max VM application heap size: 24

Eclipse: Helios Service Release 2; IDE For Java Developers.
```

The SDK & ADK are all installed and updated to their newest versions. I've set the Run Configuration What's going on?

EDIT: Googling a bit has led to Project > Clean. It now makes it to the graphical logo, then freezes.

EDIT: It now loads the simulator, but does this:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing blah activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'blah'
Uploading Hello Android.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Failed to install Hello Android.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
Launch canceled!
```

This happens whenever I try to run it.

EDIT: Removing the spaces in the app name seems to have fixed things. What a pain!

EDIT: Closed everything, tried to start from scratch after the first success, still dead... > 10 mins wait on the graphical android logo screen.

Comment: JRE Update 24 led to a bunch of buggy eclipse installs. Might want to downgrade to 22 and see if it works then. Remember to uninstall current and force your install to run the older JRE install. You can do this by specifying a VM in your eclipse.ini file. There's a wiki page @ Eclipse Dev Community talking about eclipse.ini, google it.

Comment: @Francisco: Is this the one? https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jre-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to resolve this issue, as the computer I was working with failed its HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can take a long time for the emulator to start. Sometimes around 5 minutes. Remember that it is essentially booting up a virtual device, its not like just starting some program. Normally you can follow along in the log to see what is currently going on. With the advent of the "snapshot", this can be sped up a bunch with it only really having to boot up once.

Comment: It takes > 10 mins on the graphical Android log screen. I quit it after that. Shouldn't it have screenshotted from the first time it successfully ran?

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS 10:  Installing Android Studio 3 (never used before)

1. Rebuild gradle (error alert) and then REBOOT Android Studio.  I then could rebuild my application
2. set the deployment target to the latest Android OS - rebuild and run... after a few minutes the alert at the bottom of the studio windows informs me that its running... NO window.
3. REBOOT Android Studio again,  this time I rebuild, run and the emulator window comes right up.

SO - Android Studio on win 10 64 does emulate with enough reboots!  If you have never installed it before (like me) it would be easy to go down a rabbit hole,  try rebooting after you do the logical things and it more than likely will emulate.